# How to add "or" in SQL select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am creating a report to get customer wise incoming payment in a particular period. Payment can be received through Cheques, Direct Bank Transfers, Cash. This payments saved in the database in a separate column like cheques in "CheckSum"  column,Cash amount in "cash sum column".

My question is how to get payment amount from any kind of payment type in to a single column. Following query I used to get values and I just add "or" there to get an idea.

```
select 
    convert(varchar, a.DocDate, 110) as DocDate,
    a.CardCode, a.CardName, d.SlpName, e.CheckNum,
    (CashSum or CreditSum or CheckSum or TrsfrSum) as DocTotal 
from 
    ORCT a
left join 
    RCT2 b on b.DocNum = a.DocNum
left join 
    OINV c on c.DocNum = b.DocEntry
left join 
    OSLP d on d.SlpCode = c.SlpCode
left join 
    RCT1 e on e.DocNum = a.DocEntry
```

Final output should display as follows

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Please post sample data for all your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following expression should do it (assuming other columns are NULL or zero):

```
ISNULL(CashSum,0) + ISNULL(CreditSum,0) + ISNULL(CheckSum,0) + ISNULL(TrsfrSum,0) as DocTotal
```